# what is the formula used in the scale_quantile function in R?

Tags: r

I want to know what formula is being is in the package scale_quantile by the dynutils package. I want to check if I can achieve the same results as with manual calculations like this

```
# Air quality dataset
data = datasets::airquality

# Manual calculation
dat = data$Wind

#Calcuate quantile
q_995 = quantile(dat, 0.995)
q_005 = quantile(dat, 0.005)

#Filtering the data based on the quantile value
dat = dat[dat >= q_005 & dat <= q_995]

MEAN = mean(dat)
SD = sd(dat)

manual = (dat - MEAN)/SD
```

This is the site I referred for documentation, [Documentation of scale_quantile](https://rdrr.io/cran/dynutils/man/scale_quantile.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in the source code or just look at the [dynutils Github](https://github.com/dynverse/dynutils/blob/e5ba01601ed57e88ad648eec1923b9fcca5f319f/R/scaling.R#L103-L120).

```r
scale_quantile <- function(x, outlier_cutoff = .05) {
  if (is.null(dim(x))) {
    sc <- scale_quantile(matrix(x, ncol = 1), outlier_cutoff = outlier_cutoff)
    out <- sc[,1]
    names(out) <- names(x)
    attr(out, "addend") <- attr(sc, "addend")
    attr(out, "multiplier") <- attr(sc, "multiplier")
    out
  } else {
    quants <- apply(x, 2, stats::quantile, c(outlier_cutoff, 1 - outlier_cutoff), na.rm = TRUE)

    addend <- -quants[1,]
    divisor <- apply(quants, 2, diff)
    divisor[divisor == 0] <- 1

    apply_quantile_scale(x, addend, 1 / divisor)
  }
}
```

Comment: David Gibson, Thank you very much. This really is very intuitive.

Comment: of course! also if you are using R studio if you just enter the function name you can see the code behind it. So just enter `scale_quantile` in the console and it will return the source code